# Can one table's composite primary key be used as part of a composite primary key on another table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created the three tables.table 1's unique key is used as table 2's composite primary key along with the table 2's unique key. I tried to use the part of table 2's composite key in table 3's composite key. But iam unable to do it? can any one tell me y?

```
table 1: 
create table emp1( 
    associate_id number(5) not null, 
    associate_name varchar2(25), 
    salary decimal(10,2),
    doj date,
    grade varchar2(6),
    constraint emp1_cons unique(associate_id)
);

table 2:
create table project(
    associate_id number references emp1(associate_id) not null, 
    pm_id number(5), 
    project_id varchar2(10) unique,
    project_name varchar2(20),
    project_desc varchar2(20),
    status varchar2(20),
    grade varchar2(6),
    primary key(associate_id,project_id)
);

table 3:
create table department(
    dept_id varchar2(5), 
    project_id varchar2 references project(project_id), 
    dept_name varchar2(10), 
    dept_code number(5), 
    proj_startdate date, 
    proj_enddate date, 
    primary key(dept_id,project_id)
);
```

while executing it says missing left paranthesis....

How can i create the composite primary key using the part of another tables composite primary key?

Answer (score 1):

Your schema design seems a bit flawed. What kind of constraint are you trying to do?

I don't understand why you use composite keys.

```
create table emp1(
    associate_id number(5) not null, -- PK
    associate_name varchar2(25), 
    salary decimal(10,2), 
    doj date,
    grade varchar2(6),
    primary key(associate_id)
);

create table project(
    project_id varchar2(10), -- PK
    associate_id number references emp1(associate_id) not null, 
    pm_id number(5), 
    project_name varchar2(20), 
    project_desc varchar2(20),
    status varchar2(20),
    grade varchar2(6),
    primary key(project_id)
);

create table department(
    dept_id varchar2(5),  -- PK
    project_id varchar2 references project(project_id),
    dept_name varchar2(10), 
    dept_code number(5), 
    proj_startdate date, 
    proj_enddate date, 
    primary key(dept_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Oracle (it helps to say!), you forgot to specify the size of department.project_id.